# Magento 2 how to use function $this->_getReadAdapter(); in model

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

in magento 1 their is method `$this->_getReadAdapter();` in model class.
How we can use this in Magento 2.

Comment: specify your requirement in detail.

Comment: i want to load my custom module by my custom field.

Comment: Dp you mean, you want to load your custom model by custom field, right?

Comment: check it by $this->getConnection();

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$this->_getConnection('write');` or `$this->_getConnection('read');` as per your need. make sure you have extend your ResourceModel class from `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`.